# Launching debugger from windows service fails

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-services

Currently I have the following statement in my code to allow me to debug windows services:

```
#If DEBUG Then
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()
#End If
```

I place this in the OnStart method and when I start up the service I can attach to my instance of Visual Studio.  Currently I have an instance where this is failing.  I have the service installed on a virtual machine and I'm running into the following error:

> An unhandled exception ('Launch for user') occurred in
>   MyService.exe [376]. Just-In-Time debugging this
>   exception failed with the following error: Debugger could not be
>   started because no user is logged on.

I've never had a problem debugging services like this on my local machine so I'm not sure what's going on.  The user is set to log on as `LocalSystem` if that matters.  I am logged on to the virtual machine via Administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting the following statement in the **OnStart** method:

```
#If DEBUG Then
    While True

    End While
#End If
```

This allows me to manually attach to the process in visual studio and set a break point in the while loop.  Once I hit the breakpoint I manually step outside of the while loop to proceed with the rest of the application.